# Add a Facebook LoginButton on Mainstoryboard

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-login

we've used Cocoapods to install FacebookCore and FacebookLogin, however, we want to use the LoginButton in our Mainstoryboard. We've made a view with class `LoginButton` and module `FacebookLogin`

In our viewcontroller we assign the delegate to the button as follow:

```
    @IBOutlet weak var facebookLogin: LoginButton!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
    user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser
    self.ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    if user != nil {
        let vc = 
        self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Home")
        self.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    //Facebook login
    self.facebookLogin.delegate = self

}
```

We've also implemented the `loginButtonDidCompleteLogin` and `loginButtonDidLogOut`but the button won't show when we start-up the emulator.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to add Facebook Button to your project, you have to add a `UIButton` to your `ViewController` and then change its class to `FBSDKLoginButton`. Check the image below:[image: button]

If you want to customize it, create a class and extend `FBSDKLoginButton`, and then instead of adding `FBSDKLoginButton` in your custom class, insert your customized class.

Comment: Don't I have to import the Facebook SDK then?

Comment: You said you used Cocoapods to handle dependencies so you should already have it in your project. You only have to add the `import` line in your custom class

Comment: Alright, I was mixing up Facebook SDK and Cocoapods, tyvm!